# read properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

```
propsdatabase = new Properties();    
try 
{
    // load a properties file
    InputStream dbin = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/database.properties");

    //props.load(in);
    propsdatabase.load(dbin);    
} 
catch (IOException ex) 
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I Want to access a file which is out of the jar file. just in the location of the jar file.

I am using a properties file named database.properties  in main/resources folder  .
The requirement is to change the location of database.properties outside the jar.

So I need something where the path can point to the location where the jar is .

I am using maven to build my jar

Comment: You can define absolute path for the property file as `Class.getResourceAsStream ("/some/pkg/resource.properties");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways by defining absolute path for the pro

```
Class.getResourceAsStream ("/some/pkg/resource.properties");
```

And

```
  ResourceBundle.getBundle ("some.pkg.resource");
```

Comment: I want the properties file outside the jar file

Comment: You can do it by the above way. Try it

Answer (score 3):

```
FileInputStream dbin = new FileInputStream("/my/folder/database.properties");
```

Comment: String path = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath(); gives me the path till bin folder . /D:/PropertyFile/Property/bin I have my property file in /D:/PropertyFile/Property/database.properties.

Comment: How Do I get the path "/D:/PropertyFile/Property/database.properties"